# Am I injecting this Angular2 service incorrectly? (Ionic2 project)

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-services

I have the following service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class MovieService {
  static get parameters() {
    return [[Http]];
  }

  constructor(private http:Http) {

  }

  searchMovies(movieName) {
    var url = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=&query=' + encodeURI(movieName) + '&api_key=5fbddf6b517048e25bc3ac1bbeafb919';
    var response = this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json());
    return response;
  }
}
```

(I'm not actually sure what the purpose of the get parameters function is as I got it from an example, but it's presence doesn't seem to be causing any issues)

I am attempting to inject the service into a component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import {MovieService} from '../../services/psa-web-api.service';


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/browsed/browsed.html',
  providers:[MovieService]
})
export class BrowsedPage {
  constructor(private movieService: MovieService, public navCtrl: NavController) {
  }
}
```

but every time I serve the application and access it via the browser it spits out the following console error:

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise):
EXCEPTION: Error in ./MyApp class MyApp_Host - inline template:0:0
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for ConnectionBackend! ORIGINAL STACKTRACE: Error: DI Exception
```

I haven't been able to find much of anything online regarding this error exept this post which was not super helpful: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/z7jnb6goZUQ

EDIT: adding this for further context, my app.ts file:

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, ionicBootstrap } from 'ionic-angular';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  template: '<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>',
  providers: []
})
export class MyApp {...}

ionicBootstrap(MyApp, [HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My `app.ts` looks like this

```
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';


@Component({
 templateUrl: "build/app.html",
  providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS]
})
```

and then

```
ionicBootstrap(MyApp) //without the HTTP_PROVIDERS
```

Comment: This fixed it! Seems as though `ionicBootstra()` isn't injecting the `HTTP_PROVIDERS` as I thought it should be.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know **Ionic** so I might be wrong but in Angular2 **HttpModule** is required in order to deal with **Http**. (***RC5 an later versions***)

```
import { HttpModule} from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,        //<------HttpModule is required to import
],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```

**RC4**

```
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,       //<-----need to inject here
  ....
])
```

Comment: So I'm actually not using NgModule because the version of Ionic I am using is still running on angular2 RC4 (pre-module IIRC)

Comment: Check updated answer. But still it belongs to Angular2. Please note I don't know Ionic. So answer may or may not help you.

Comment: I actually thought that might be the problem and immediately after asking the question tried injecting the providers there...alas it did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try without the `get parameters` method, since is not needed anymore (it was used in previous versions of Ionic2 I think, so probably the example you got is not updated)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class MovieService {

  constructor(private http:Http) {

  }

  searchMovies(movieName) {
    var url = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=&query=' + encodeURI(movieName) + '&api_key=5fbddf6b517048e25bc3ac1bbeafb919';
    var response = this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json());
    return response;
  }
}
```

Also try without importing the `HTTP_PROVIDERS`

`import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';`

so your `ionicBootstrap` would look like this:

```
ionicBootstrap(MyApp);
```

Comment: Hmmm... could you please use this [starter plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/vEjjdH) and add your code there? Maybe we can reproduce the error and take a look to see what's going on :)

Comment: See Ivaro18's answer above for the solution.